# Add ads to android apps

Tags: android, kotlin, ads

I'm facing an issue with integrating Google Ads into my Android app, and despite my best efforts, it is not working. I have followed the necessary steps and guidelines provided by Google, but the ads are not being displayed. I have also checked for any coding errors or issues with the ad unit, but everything appears to be correct. This problem is affecting the revenue generation of my app and hindering its overall performance. I'm require a solution to this problem that will enable you to successfully integrate and display Google Ads in my Android app.

The app Link :
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hB6q8zgi0sjT0T0ehrTkfa8fTQLr2KXd?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

There is an activity for this in Android Studio left click on app new>Google> and then the first option to bring ads in.